# Did a Soyuz fly with a Union Jack?

Tags: identify-this-object, soyuz-launcher, soviet-union

In [this schematic of a Soyuz rocket](https://drawingdatabase.com/soyuz-rocket/), the payload fairing is depicted with the flag of the USSR on one side, and what appears to be the flag of the United Kingdom on the other.

[image]

Did the Soyuz ever fly with the UK flag on it?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The USSR's next-to-last crewed launch was [Soyuz TM-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_TM-12), flying to Mir, carrying two Russians and the UK's first astronaut, [Helen Sharman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helen_Sharman).

Here's a photo of TM-12 on the launch pad with the UK flag visible.

[image]

Several nations partnered with the USSR and sent astronauts to Mir during this time period, and in each case the appropriate national flags were painted or decaled on the launcher.

Comment: Stupid question - ...they removed the flag before takeoff right?

Comment: @BruceWayne I would guess the flag was not a textile one, but simply painted on.

Comment: Technically she would be a cosmonaut rather than an astronaut, surely?

Comment: @PeterTaylor - That sounds like an excellent question for the main site

Comment: @PeterTaylor No, her profession is whatever her sponsoring agency [Project Juno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Juno) says it is. NASA crews don’t become cosmonauts when riding on Soyuz either. (It’s a silly distinction anyway.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronaut#Terminology